# What does the javax.net.ssl warning "user_canceled" mean?

Tags: ssl, java-8

I'm connecting to a server via SSL. This worked fine with OpenJDK8 262 and 265.

With 275, I'm suddenly seeing this in the output:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5F|pool-1-thread-1|2021-03-02 10:47:27.085 CET|Logger.java:765|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "warning",
  "description": "user_canceled"
}
```

I tracked this down to this constant (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8/blob/6a383433a9f4661a96a90b2a4c7b5b9a85720031/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/Alerts.java#L76):

```
static final byte           alert_user_canceled = 90;
```

When I search the repo for this constant, I get only a single hit (in a method to convert the code into a string):

```
    case alert_user_canceled:
        return "user_canceled";
```

Searching all of OpenJDK sources yields the same hits: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aopenjdk+alert_user_canceled&type=code

I'm stumped. Who sends this warning and why?

Update: After some more testing, I'm getting the impression that the remote side sends the "cancel". Is that possible? For me, this doesn't make sense since I connect to a server (I send ClientHello, I receive ServerHello).

Comment: Yes "Received alert" means the remote sent it. 90 _should_ (per RFC) not be used for protocol error, so what could or should cause it depends entirely on the remote, which you didn't describe or identify. You could set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` for both working and broken versions and look for differences that might matter to the server, but that's mostly guesswork.

Comment: Do you have tcpdump for that TCP connection?

Comment: @JanGaraj No, it's a client server where I'm limited to what I can install.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah! I totally missed that piece of information. I'll try to get the sysadmin to start the server with these options.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is an alert (as defined in the [TLS Protocol Specification,  Section 7.2 "Alert Protocol"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2)) sent by the server you are attempting to handshake with.

In the specification linked above, the alert code of `90` (`user_canceled`) is described as follows:

> This handshake is being canceled for some reason unrelated to a
> protocol failure.  If the user cancels an operation after the
> handshake is complete, just closing the connection by sending a
> close_notify is more appropriate.  This alert should be followed
> by a close_notify.  This message is generally a warning.

In a nutshell, this says that this specific alert code is meant to indicate implementation specific reasons to cancel the handshake procedure. So without knowing what server software is running on the other end, it is impossible to say what exactly went wrong.

You can try to debug the connection by comparing detailed logs of the handshake procedure from the working version with the broken version, and see what is different. This *might* give some insight about how to solve this issue.